# Check in twig if at least on property exists in a given array

Tags: twig, frontend

Let's assume I have an array `$cars` where `$cars = [$toyota, $vw]` and

```
$toyota= [
    'id' => 1,
    'color' => 'green',
  ];

$vw= [
    'id' => 7,
    'color' => 'red',
  ];
```

I wanna do a check in `twig` to see if at least one of the cars ID exists in a dedicated array (`[3, ,7, 15]`).

What's the best way to do this? Doing a `for` loop is not ideal since I cannot do a `break` if I found the first element matching my criteria. And I also don't wanna print a text twice if both elements satisfy the condition. I just want to print a text if one element does.

I tried doing something weird like
`{% if cars in [3, 7, 15] %} .... {% endif %}` but if obvously doesn't work since I need to check the `id` of a car, not the object...

Any suggestions on how to best solve this is much appreciated.

P.S. I know using `array_filter` in the controller makes it much easier, but sadly that doesn't work for me. That's because I use AJAX and after a submit, I won't have access to `cars` anymore. Therefore, I need to do it in the view..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (see https://twigfiddle.com/8u3eh5):

```
{% set found = false %}

{% for car in cars %}
    {% if car.id in ids %}
        {% set found = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if found %}
    found
{% else %}
    not found
{% endif %}
```

However, even if this is a working solution, you will be better off by implementing this in PHP code and expose such a function as a [Twig test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#tests).

Comment: Twig tests might do the trick. I just need to figure out what the `new Twig_Environment($loader);` means and where the `loader` is coming from.

Comment: In which context do you use Twig? Did you set it up yourself or do you use a framework?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new filter to `twig`

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('has', function($haystack, $needles) {
    if (!is_array($needles)) $needles = [ $needles, ];
    return count(array_intersect($haystack, $needles)) > 0;
});
```

Which you then can use like the following inside `twig`

```
{% set data = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'lorem', 'lipsum' ] %}
{% if data | has('foo') %}
    data contains foo
{% endif %}

{% if data | has(['lorem', 'lipsum', 'boat']) %}
    data contains lorem, lipsum or boat
{% endif %}
```